# When is getdate and strptime not included in time.h?

Tags: c, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

So the function [`getdate_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getdate_r) seems to be undefined for me; compiling the following doesn't work in either gcc or clang, (the man page program also doesn't work)

```
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    char timeString[] = "2015/01/01 10:30:50";
    struct tm res = {0};
    int err = getdate_r(timeString, &res);
    return err;
}
```

clang reports the following

```
test.c:6:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getdate_r' is invalid
      in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int err = getdate_r(timeString, &res);
                  ^
1 warning generated.
```

Other functions from `time.h` such as `getdate`, `strptime` also don't work in a similar manner.

**Anyone have an explanation on whats going on?**

clang version information

```
Ubuntu clang version 3.6.0-2ubuntu1 (tags/RELEASE_360/final) (based on LLVM 3.6.0)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Just a guess, did you try defining `_GNU_SOURCE` MACRO?

Comment: It'd be useful to show which compiler flags you are using; e.g. if you are compiling in ISO C mode then this result is correct because `getdate_r` and `strptime` are not ISO C functions

Comment: the man page is relatively explicit on this, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `getdate_r` available you need to:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
```

*before* including any include files. Doing so will provide declarations for various GNU extensions including `getdate_r`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    char timeString[] = "2015/01/01 10:30:50";
    struct tm res = {0};
    int err = getdate_r(timeString, &res);
    return err;
}
```